# How to read and fetch or access content from .icc file types

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

How to perform read operation on .icc files and How to fetch or access the particular data or content from uploaded file of type .icc extension and show it in another text field.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of/can find any Ruby based tools that can print out the information in an [ICC color profile](http://www.color.org/iccprofile.xalter) but, there are lots of other open source tools for making and editing ICC profiles:

- http://www.color.org/profilingtools.xalter
- http://www.color.org/opensource.xalter

Here's a [profile dump tool](http://www.color.org/profdump.xalter) but it only runs on Windows.

I haven't tried many of the aforementioned tools (there's a lot!) but I imagine you'd have to find amongst those a command line tool that can parse and dump the information from an ICC file into a readable format and pass it to `STDOUT`.

Then you can just shell out in Ruby:

```
@icc_dump = `some_icc_cli_tool /path/to/some_profile.icc`
```

*Note the [backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60)*

And get back some text representing the headers and fields of the color profile. On Mac I can just open up ColorSync and be able to open and read any color profile on my system. So there definitely is a way. Hopefully this pushes you in the right direction :)